# ClaseFileReader

Tags: java, filereader

Estoy leyendo ficheros con la clase `FileReader` pero el primer carácter no lo coge, al realizar el bucle `while` es extraño porque el archivo del que lee, es un texto y está correcto.

```
package accesoarchivos;

import java.io.*;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class AccesoArchivos {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Lectura accediendo = new Lectura();

        try {
            accediendo.leeArchivo();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(AccesoArchivos.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

}

class Lectura {

    public void leeArchivo() throws IOException {

        try {
            FileReader entrada = new FileReader("C://Users//enriq//Desktop//archivo.txt");

            int c = entrada.read();

            while (c != -1) {

                c = entrada.read();
                
                

                System.out.print((char)c);
                
                
                
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Lectura.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: El código se ve bien. Tal vez haya algún problema con la codificación del archivo. ¿Cuál es la codificación?

Answer (score 1):

El problema radica en que lees el primer carácter fuera del ciclo, luego, ya estando dentro del `while` vuelve a leer el siguiente caracter y el primero literalmente lo pierdes.

Puedes corregirlo de la siguiente manera:

```
int c;
while((c=fr.read())!=-1) {
  System.out.print((char)c);
}
```